# I am receiving an IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL BSOD

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, troubleshooting

I've been trying to fix this myself, but I would like to yield some results and this blue screen doesn't come up unless I'm playing a game and right now I'm exhausted... I updated my Nvidia 880GTS drivers and I updated my Realtek HD drivers in an attempt to fix what could possibly be the driver causing the error. I have attempted to check my memory for errors with no bad result. I was getting some clipping when I booted, which went away when I installed the new video drivers...I am hoping that this has solved it, but I'd like to keep going and get some advice. Yes, I can see that I need to download the symbols, but the error presents itself without doing so (I have DSL and...yeah...impatient, anyway..). I would like to identify the STACK results but do not know how.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Autumn\Desktop\Mini070410-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
```

Comment: How to get a stack trace on Windows:
http://community.gemstone.com/display/GSS64/How+to+get+a+stack+trace+on+Windows

Answer (score 2):

You need the symbols loaded or WinDBG can't properly report the entire command stack, making it's results pretty much useless (or rather, not much more useful than the blue screen itself).

Go to [Microsoft's Page Here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/debugstart.mspx) about Windows debugging to get the correct symbols for your OS and some info on how to install/interpret them.

Basically you want to download the symbols for Vista 64-bit, extract them into "c:\symbols", and then set "SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols" as the symbol path in WinDbg.

Once this is done (yeah I know, they're huge) and you run the commands you ran last time, it will (hopfully) be able to trace back to the specific failure and tell you what failed and what called it to make it fail.

Once you know that, you have suspects. :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that it would affect the stack id since it was showing up already.

Comment: Alright, so now I'm using BlueScreenView because WinDMG or awful and won't even load the symbols even when I tried a hundred times in multiple ways to fix the damn thing. SO! BSV showed the errors INSTANTLY and I am relieved.

I am getting a few errors. One is my network card, which I am updating as I type. The other two are portcls.sys and ndis.sys...I am unsure about them and am researching as I go, but I'm frightened that I have multiple errors. :(